# IIS Express and URL Rewrite not working

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-express

Is there a way to use url rewrite with IIS Express on a Windows 10 machine? If I try to install the URL Rewrite 2.0 module via Webplattform installer, I am getting an error. It seems to run only with the non express version.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite module is shipped with IIS Express. No need to install any extra thing.

Comment: But I can't see it in the iis manager and if I try to use it in my web.config, I receive an 500.19 error.

Comment: IIS Manager is for full IIS, not IIS Express. You'd better first learn their differences. If you are talking about full IIS then URL rewrite module is a separate download.

Comment: Here is the solution for the problem: http://forums.iis.net/t/1223421.aspx?Can+not+install+rewrite+module+on+windows+10+10041+build+IIS10